# Accessing Quarkus Swagger UI in K8s environment

Tags: kubernetes, swagger-ui, quarkus, nginx-ingress

I have deployed the quarkus service in K8s and is running behind the ingress controller. I am able to reach the Swagger UI in browser but I have problem sending Rest request as the namespace is removed from the URL.
My Ingress configuration is as follows 
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` 
`path: /{{ namespace }}(/|$)(.*)` 
I can send Rest request using CURL command from outside.
The openapi-path is default: /q/openapi and http.root-path uses default configuration.Do I need to include any additional configuration to enable Swagger UI request.

Comment: You can't activate it with the property **quarkus.swagger-ui.enable**. This property needs to be set to **true**, **quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include**, in application.properties or in build time with: **mvn package -Dquarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true**.

Comment: This config is already set. I could see the swagger UI in k8s environment but I had path issues related to rest request from swagger UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the server details in either

1. An annotation (https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-open-api-2.0/microprofile-openapi-spec-2.0.html#_servers) or
2. in config `quarkus.smallrye-openapi.servers`

You might also have to do some CORS configuration, see https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#cors-filter

Comment: The config `quarkus.smallrye-openapi.servers` solves the problem with respect to sending rest request from swagger ui. However, the swagger ui landing page always points to /q/openapi/ in Explore textbox without namespace prefix. Do I need to set `quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path`?

Comment: Yes I think that should do it